# Target only one element with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a little problem with Angular, but I really don't find any solution.  
I have a ngRepeat  with several elements. One of them, a simple button, had to change color on click. But if I click on it, other buttons change color too. 
How can I target only one ?

In my Controller :

```
$scope.changeClass = function(){
    var x = angular.element(this);
    $scope.class = "icon-fav";
    if ($scope.class === "icon-fav"){
        $scope.class = "icon-fav-clicked";
    }
    else{
      $scope.class = "icon-fav";
    }
};
```

HTML :

```
<button ng-class="class" class="actions-icon animated bounceInUp icon-fav" ng-click="changeClass();tagLike(post)" ng-show="isLoggedIn()"></button>
```

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a "clicked" attribute on you objects in the ngRepeat, and use ng-style to set the class.

Quick and dirty example:

```
<button ng-class="{'icon-fav-clicked': post.clicked, 'icon-fav': !post.clicked}" class="actions-icon animated bounceInUp icon-fav" ng-click="post.clicked=true;tagLike(post)" ng-show="isLoggedIn()"></button>
```

You can set the post.clicked = true in the tagLike() function for a cleaner ng-click.

Comment: You are welcome, and BTW - you should try to avoid making DOM changes via the controller as much as possible, it's not the best practice. Try learning about directives for UI manipulation, as that is their purpose :)